# Terraform AKS and reference to node_resource_group

Tags: terraform, azure-aks

So I'm trying to create an application gateway using Terraform to use as the AGIC. I would like to have the resources for this in the same resource group as the nodes, which is auto created.

AKS

```
# Create aks cluster
# A new resource group will be auto created for node_resource_group
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                            = "${var.RESOURCE_GRP_NAME}-AKS"
  location                        = var.LOCATION
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.k8s_resource_grp.name
  dns_prefix                      = "${var.RESOURCE_GRP_NAME}-AKS"
  node_resource_group             = "${var.RESOURCE_GRP_NAME}-INF"
  kubernetes_version              = var.KUBERNETES.KubernetesVersion
  api_server_authorized_ip_ranges = var.KUBERNETES_ALLOWED_IP_RANGES
  tags                            = var.TAGS


  default_node_pool {
    name                = "default"
    type                = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    node_count          = var.KUBERNETES.NodeCount
    availability_zones  = var.KUBERNETES.AvailabilityZones
    vm_size             = var.KUBERNETES.NodeVmSize
    enable_auto_scaling = var.KUBERNETES.AutoScaleBool
    os_disk_size_gb     = var.KUBERNETES.OSDiskSize
    max_pods            = var.KUBERNETES.MaxPods
    node_labels         = var.KUBERNETES.Labels
    node_taints         = var.KUBERNETES.Taints
    min_count           = var.KUBERNETES.AutoScaleMinCount
    max_count           = var.KUBERNETES.AutoScaleMaxCount
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = true

    azure_active_directory {
      managed = true
      admin_group_object_ids = var.KUBERNETES.AdminGroupObjectIds
    }
  }

  addon_profile {
    oms_agent {
      enabled = true
      log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics_workspace.id
    }
    kube_dashboard {
      enabled = false
    }
    azure_policy {
      enabled = true
    }
  }

  network_profile {
    load_balancer_sku  = "standard"
    outbound_type      = "loadBalancer"
    network_plugin     = "azure"
    network_policy     = "azure"
    dns_service_ip     = "10.0.0.10"
    docker_bridge_cidr = "172.17.0.1/16"
    service_cidr       = "10.0.0.0/16"
  }
}
```

Just trying something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "aks_vnet" {
    name                        = "vnet"
    location                    = var.LOCATION
    resource_group_name         = "${var.RESOURCE_GRP_NAME}-INF"
    address_space               = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
    tags                        = var.TAGS
    depends_on = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks]
}
```

Returns `Error: Cycle: azurerm_virtual_network.aks_vnet, azurerm_subnet.pods_subnet, azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks`

Why can't the `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` be used in `depends_on`?

I also tried to reference the resource group that will be created like:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "aks_vnet" {
    name                        = "vnet"
    location                    = var.LOCATION
    resource_group_name         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.node_resource_group
    address_space               = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
    tags                        = var.TAGS
}
```

Which gives me `Error: Cycle: azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks, azurerm_virtual_network.aks_vnet, azurerm_subnet.pods_subnet`

---

Why is this happening? I can't reference anything inside `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: You can't. At least not in an easy and recommended way.

It is possible to place your VNet in that resource group, but not if you want to use it for AKS as well. Based on your error message I expect you are using `azurerm_subnet.pods_subnet` in your AKS setup like `vnet_subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.pods_subnet.id` (in `default_node_pool`), which indeed creates a cyclic dependency.

It is possible to import the managed VNet (which is created for AKS when you don't specify `vnet_subnet_id` and add subnets in this VNet for AGIC, but I wouldn't recommend that.